# Polymer elements as attributes

Tags: javascript, polymer

Is it possible to inlude polymer elements using HTML attributes instead of HTML tags? For example:

```
<div some-polymer-behavior></div>
```

I think it is more convenient to use attributes than wrapping code into HTML tags if I want to decorate an existing element with some functionality.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [extending native HTML elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#type-extension).

Your element is

```
Polymer({
   is: 'my-div-extension',
   extends: 'div'
});
```

And the usage is

```
<div is="my-div-extension"></div>
```

Unfortunately, this comes with a few drawbacks, which you should be aware of:

1. It's not standardized and [likely to be obsolete before Web Components spec is finished](https://component.kitchen/blog/posts/writing-a-web-component-that-wraps-a-standard-html-element-might-alleviate-the-need-for-is-syntax).
2. It is not ([yet](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2280)) possible to extend other Polymer elements

   - You can use [behaviors](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors) instead
3. It is not possible to extend multiple native elements in one go

   - A wrapper element would be a better fit
4. You cannot apply multiple extensions to one tag like `<div behavior-one behavior-two>`